# Problems with creating an array of objects in java

Tags: java

I'm creating an array of objects. The 'Board' constructor needs to create an array of 'Space' objects. Currently, this is how I'm doing it.

```
public class Board {
    //...

    public void Board(int len){
        //...
        Space[] array = new Space[len];
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            int[] stuffs = new int[4];
            //...
            array[i]= new Space(i, stuffs, 0, 0);
        }
```

I've removed a bunch of irrelevant code and replaced it with //..., as it does not give errors and is not related to the problems I am experiencing. If you would like to see that code, you can ask for it, but I seriously doubt it's related to the problem.

Right now, I get the following error:

```
Board.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Space(int,int[],int,int)
location: class Space
            array[i]= new Space(i, stuffs, 0, 0);
                      ^
```

I have no idea how to resolve the issue. What do?

Comment: what does the constructor of Space look like?

Comment: `I've removed a bunch of irrelevant code`. The most relevant code would be the `Space` constructors.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have a `Space` constructor with signature `Space(int, int[], int, int)`.  You need to look at what constructors are available in `Space`.

You may be including the array index unnecessarily?

Comment: or maybe you have the constructor but is not accessible?